# Paypal Webhook Response

Tags: php, sql, web, paypal

I have been trying to get Paypal's Webhooks to work but all ive been running into is problems. I am trying to make a simple payment process where the user just pays for a product and then I want to setup webhooks to alert me when the payment is made, refunded, or reversed. I have the payment process setup and that is not a problem. I am also hosting the webhook url at a SSL enabled URL.

When I have a purchase go through it sends the webhook response to the link and I have it upload a basic "test" variable to the database just to show that it is indeed being contacted. I also try to insert all of the post data into the database but that doesn't seem to work. Here is the code that the webhook contacts:

```
<?php
header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK'); 

$servername = "xxxx";
$username = "xxxx";
$password = "xxxx";
$db = "xxxx";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db);

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO vars (var) VALUES ('test')";
$conn->query($sql);

foreach ($_POST as $param_name => $param_val) {
    echo "Param: $param_name; Value: $param_val<br />\n";
    $sql = "INSERT INTO vars (var) VALUES ('" . $param_name . "')";
    $conn->query($sql);
}
?>
```

So like i said I see it insert the "test" into the database but when I try to go through the post variables (which from what i understand there should be some) it doesnt upload any variables.

But when I use the IPN simulator on the paypal developer sandbox and I send it to the link it inserts all of the post variables.

So why is it contacting the URL but not including any of the information? Am I receiving it incorrectly and not processing it right?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

First of all You should verify that this request really came from PayPal. For that you should send a little bit modified POST request back to PayPal.

```
$paypalurl = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
  $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
  $req .= "&$key=$value";
}
$ch = curl_init($paypalurl);
if ($ch == false) {
  return false;
}

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));
$res = curl_exec($ch);
```

In the response you should check if it's verified or not:

```
if ($res) && strcmp($res, "VERIFIED") == { 
    // your code here
}
```

So it's better to always use IPN simulator to test this thing, otherwise (by sending plain POST request to your script) it wouldn't be validated normally.

Besides, I would advise you to take a closer look to $_POST['payment_status'] variable. It could be "Completed" (which is ok when payment is processed normally), or "Refund", "Reversed". And process payment according to that. And of course I strongly recommend to validate input — check _POST request (for availability, possible SQL injections, etc) and then proceed to the rest.

Comment: But the problem is that it seems I dont receive any POST variables from the webhook. I do from the IPN sim though.

Comment: Your webhook script should process IPN's POST request. What other POST request do you expect?

Answer (score 2):

```
$bodyReceived = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

This is the information you'll receive from paypal as a json object